# Get active and total bookings (from 1 table) for every user in users table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

1. users:

- username (pk)

2. bookings:

- username (fk)
- status (A = Active, C = Cancelled , D = DONE)

I'm willing to show user details along with with their count of active and total bookings (where total bookings will be all the entries in "bookings" table for a particular user).

Table to show:
username, active bookings (count), total bookings (count)

Currently I'm unable to make an efficient query for this.
My DB is postgresql.

Please assist.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `PostgreSQL` you can take the advantage of `Filter()` clause. Also you have to use `Left Join` because you want the details for every user from `user` table. So Write your query like below:

```sql
select 
t1.username, 
count(*) filter (where t2.status='A') as "Active_Bookings",
count(t2.*) as "Total_Bookings"
from users t1 left join bookings t2 on t1.username=t2.username
group by 1
```

**Edit as per comment:**
`Filter` clause is supported by `Postgresql` and `SQLite`. For others `count with case` will do the thing. Below query should work for almost every other database.

```
select 
t1.username, 
count(case when t2.status='A' then 1 end)  as "Active_Bookings",
count(t2.*) as "Total_Bookings"
from users t1 left join bookings t2 on t1.username=t2.username
group by t1.username
```

you can use `sum(case when t2.status='A' then 1 else 0 end)  as "Active_Bookings"` also.

Comment: Seems to be a good approach, but "Total_Bookings" is returning 1 for every user where as "bookings" table is empty, how about we do count(t2.*) instead of count(*)?

btw I was just wondering if the db was mysql or sql server then what would have been a good approach?

Many Thanks mate

Comment: Yup Correct that `Count(*)` to `count(t2.*)` also added query for other databases

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
select u.username,count(*) as total_booking,
       count(case when status='Active' then 1 end) as active_bookings
from users u join bookings b on u.username=b.username
group by u.username
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure I udnerstood your question but based on the input you gave try this , this should work

```
select x.username,active_bookings,total_bookings from (
(select username, count(status) as active_bookings from bookings where status='A' group by username)x  join (select username,count(status) as total_bookings  from bookings group by username)y on x.username=y.username);
```